# Desbordamiento en C++, Básico

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y he escogido C/C++ como primer lenguaje. El principal problema es que no tengo conocimientos previos de bases de la programación o ingeniería informática, así que algunas cosas se me hacen un poco cuesta arriba, aunque con Google y algo de obstinación lo voy entendiendo. Hace poco he escrito un programa en C++ para probar la conjetura de Collatz con números naturales:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
 int num;
 cout << "Introduce un numero:" << '\t';
 cin >> num;
 while (num != 1) /*mientras num sea diferente de 1*/
  {
    if (num % 2 == 0) /* si num es par */
      {
        cout << num;
        cout << " /2 = ";
        num /= 2;
        cout << num; /*dividirlo entre 2*/
        cout << "\n";
      }
    else  /*si num es impar*/
      {
        cout << num;
        cout << " x3+1 = "; /*multiplicar por 3 y sumar 1*/
        num = 3 * num + 1;
        cout << num;
        cout << "\n";
      }
  }
cout << "el programa ha terminado" << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

El programa funciona correctamente, pero se "vuelve loco" al introducir un valor para num demasiado grande. Esto es debido, según he leído, a que al asignar un valor a `num` fuera del rango permitido para el tipo de datos `int`, se produce un desbordamiento/overflow. He leído también que este tipo de fallos pueden constituir un problema de seguridad importante, ya que se sobreescriben zonas de memoria no deseadas y el programa comenzaría a comportarse de forma imprevisible.

Mi pregunta es: ¿es posible que un error de este tipo en los programas que escriba comprometa la estabilidad del sistema operativo sobre el que se ejecuta?, es decir, ¿tras un desbordamiento podría sobreescribirse alguna zona de memoria crucial para el funcionamiento del OS?

Comment: Nos iría muy bien un ejemplo de entrada y salida que provoque el comportamiento que describes, así los demás lo podemos probar e investigar por qué pasa.

Comment: Lo provocan algunas entradas superiores a 2×10^9. He comprendido lo que está pasando gracias a tu comentario de más abajo. Efectivamente, la arquitectura del sistema que estoy usando es de 32 bits, por lo que supongo que el desbordamiento se produce en el momento de la lectura. Un saludo y perdonad estás dudas tan básicas.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes verificar si el problema es durante la lectura comprobando el `cin.fail()`. Recuerda también que puedes usar `long long` como tipo para tener mayor rango de números.

Answer (score 3):

> he escogido C/C++ como primer lenguaje

C es un lenguaje procedural y C++ es un lenguaje orientado a objetos. **No** son un único lenguaje sino dos. De hecho hay cosas que se son legales en C y no en C++ y viceversa.

> ¿es posible que un error de este tipo en los programas que escriba comprometa la estabilidad del sistema operativo sobre el que se ejecuta?

Cualquier entrada que sobrepase los límites de una variable puede ser una fuente de errores.

Es de tu responsabilidad como programador garantizar que las entradas son válidas y hacer que el programa se defienda ante entradas erróneas.

En el caso que muestras, bastaría con verificar los flags de error de `cin` después de cada entrada y, de producirse un error, vaciar el buffer de entrada para evitar lecturas sucias:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  int val;
  std::cin >> val;

  if( std::cin.fail() )
  {
    std::cout << "No se ha introducido un número o el rango es incorrecto\n";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
    std::cin.clear();
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "El número introducido es " << val << '\n';
  }
}
```

> ¿tras un desbordamiento podría sobreescribirse alguna zona de memoria crucial para el funcionamiento del OS?

Si el desbordamiento se produce en una variable nativa (`int`, `char`, `double`, ...) no es posible escribir, al menos no directamente, en otras zonas de memoria. Un dato de tipo `int` **siempre** va a ocupar el mismo número de bytes en tu aplicación, si se introduce un número más grande lo que sucede es que algunos bits quedarán descartados.

Supongamos que una variable únicamente ocupa 8 bytes sin signo e intentamos almacenar el número 1000:

```
1000 en binario           -> 0011 1110 1000
capacidad del dato        ->      xxxx xxxx
dato realmente almacenado ->      1110 1000 -> 232
```

Los bits descartados no van a ningun sitio. Simplemente se pierden.

El problema de sobreescribir memoria aparece cuando se utilizan punteros:

```
int datos[10];
int indice;
std::cin >> indice;
datos[indice] = 0;
```

¿Qué sucedería si, en el ejemplo anterior, se introduce un índice superior a 9 o inverior a 0? Se estará accediendo a memoria que no pertenece al vector `datos` y eso va a provocar un mal funcionamiento del programa puesto que estás modificando otras variables sin control alguno.

Otra forma de sobreescribir memoria sería con el desbordamiento en el caso de cadenas o buffers:

```
char cadena[10];
std::cin >> cadena;
```

¿Qué sucede si se introduce una cadena de más de 9 caracteres? El problema será el mismo que en el caso anterior. Acabaremos escribiendo en posiciones de memoria que no pertenecen a `cadena` y el comportamiento del programa entonces será impredecible.

Piensa que los ataques por desbordamiento suelen ser una vía de entrada para ejecutar código arbitrario en el sistema (si el proceso desbordado tiene privilegios de administrador da tu perdida la información almacenada en ese sistema).

Answer (score 2):

Buenas tardes!

No sé bien con qué fines estás incursionando en el desarrollo de software pero deberías tener en cuenta otros lenguajes que te harán la tarea más fácil. Por ejemplo, C#, Visual Basic .Net o bien inclinarte directamente al web por ASP.Net, PHP o entornos como Ruby on Rails. Todo dependerá de a qué apuntas con tus desarrollos.

Sin embargo, es vital que primero leas sobre informática en general y luego sobre teoría de algorítmica. La pregunta que estás haciendo muestra que deberías tener ciertas bases para entender lo que está pasando.

La respuesta a esa pregunta tiene muchas aristas. La respuesta más simple sería que no. Un programa que escribas no modificará un área restringida de memoria dado que esas áreas son administradas por el núcleo del sistema operativo. Sin embargo, la pregunta es tan amplia que también debería responderte que sí, es probable que un programa que escribes altere la estabilidad de un sistema operativo. Sin ir más lejos, un virus es un programa que se ejecuta sin la autorización del usuario y, como todos sabemos, puede generar más que solo inestabilidad a un sistema operativo.

Por eso, primero, intenta leer sobre Sistemas Operativos (un libro recomendado es Operating System Concepts with Java de Silberschatz) allí podrás comenzar a entender cómo funciona un ordenador. Luego, deberás explorar la teoría de la programación. Un libro viejito pero buenito es Fundamentos de la programación de Luis Joyanes Aguilar.

Por último, sí, elije un entorno de desarrollo de software con su lenguaje de programación.

Espero te haya servido de ayuda!

Comment: Hola Ignacio, muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta! Soy profesional sanitario y mi idea es introducirme en la bioinformática (actualmente mi presupuesto no me permite estudiar un máster relacionado con este campo). Pensé en aprender Python y R (para el ámbito bioestadístico), pero un compañero informático me recomendó comenzar con C/C++ para "adquirir las bases" (en sus propias palabras). Gracias a tu comentario he entendido que las bases son la teoría de sistemas operativos y de programación, no un lenguaje determinado. Muchas gracias otra vez por tu respuesta y las aclaraciones.

Answer (score 0):

> El programa [...] se "vuelve loco" al introducir un valor para num demasiado grande. Esto es debido, según he leído, a que al asignar un valor a num fuera del rango permitido para el tipo de datos int

#### Rango de un entero (`int`).

El rango de un entero sin signo varía según la arquitectura del sistema. A día de hoy los sistemas pueden ser de 32 o 64 bits (muy raramente de 16), así que la cantidad de números que podrá almacenar un `int` será:

- Para sistemas de 32 bits, 2<sup>32</sup>: 4.294.967.296.
- Para sistemas de 64 bits, 2<sup>64</sup>: 18.446.744.073.709.551.616.

Si los números se te están desbordando, apuesto a que estás trabajando en un sistema de 32 bits. Como estás usando un entero sin signo, la mitad de los valores se usarán para valores con signo y la otra mitad para valores sin signo, así que el mayor valor positivo que puedes almacenar será:

- Para sistemas de 32 bits: 2.147.483.647.
- Para sistemas de 64 bits: 9.223.372.036.854.775.807 .

#### ¿Dónde se desborda tu valor?

Por lo que puedo ver con una rápida lectura de tu código, hay dos puntos en que puedes tener desbordamiento de un entero (`int`).

1. En la lectura: `cin >> num;`.
2. En la multiplicación: `num = 3 * num + 1;`.

**Lectura**.

Si al leer introduces un valor mayor al que `num` es capaz de almacenar, la variable `num` obtendrá un valor *extraño*<sup>1</sup> y en consecuencia todas las operaciones posteriores fallarán porque el valor inicial es erróneo.

Si usas una versión de compilador anterior a 1998 (no creo, pero hay que mencionarlo) `std::cin` no escribe en la variable hasta que ha descodificado con éxito la entrada, así que en caso de fallo `num` quedaría con el valor inicial. Como no le has dado valor inicial, el valor que tiene es indeterminado y en consecuencia todas las operaciones posteriores fallarán porque el valor inicial también es erróneo.

En ambos casos, si el valor introducido supera el rango de la variable en que se lee, podrás saber si la lectura ha fallado consultando el retorno de [`std::cin::fail`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail):

```
int num = 0;
cout << "Introduce un numero:" << '\t';
cin >> num;

if (cin.fail())
{
    cout << "Hubo un fallo en la lectura!\n";
}
```

**Multiplicación**.

Puedes provocar un desbordamiento de valor entero al operar sobre el mismo. El entero (`int`) es el tipo implícito de los literales numéricos y las operaciones que realizas.

Por ejemplo, si tienes un valor muy próximo al límite de valores del entero, al multiplicar por `3` seguro que obtienes un valor mayor a lo que `num` puede almacenar. Esto provocará un desbordamiento y el valor resultante no tendrá sentido (se "volverá loco"), tampoco lo tendrán los valores resultantes tras operar con este valor.

#### Soluciones.

**Cambia de `int` a `long long`**.

Siempre habrá un límite hasta el que podrás operar con tipos básicos, pero si no estabas usando el tipo más grande permitido en tu compilador, cambia a un tipo mayor. El tipo `long long` es de 64 bits y soportado por los compiladores C++ modernos más populares.

**Usa una librería**.

Si incluso un entero de 64 bits se te queda corto, hay una manera de superar las limitaciones de los tipos básicos. Podrías usar una librería de enteros largos o enteros de precisión múltiple. La librería [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) ofrece uno de estos tipos.

#### Memoria afectada.

> ¿tras un desbordamiento podría sobreescribirse alguna zona de memoria crucial para el funcionamiento del OS?

Las operaciones aritméticas con tipos numéricos no sobre-escriben memoria alguna, en el peor de los casos te darán valores erróneos pero nunca afectarán a la memoria circundante. La única manera de sobre-escribir memoria en C++ es mediante aritmética de punteros (que no es tu caso) y aún así, es difícil acceder a memoria crucial del sistema operativo ya que éste controla los accesos a memoria de las aplicaciones y si una intenta leer/escribir en un espacio que no tiene asignado, bloqueará dicho intento y la aplicación fallará.

---

<sup>1</sup>Si usas un compilador antiguo, `num` no se modificaría. Los estándares más modernos intentan descodificar la entrada hasta el punto que el entero se desborda y dejan de descodificar en ese momento, el valor que queda en la variable es el resultado de ese intento.